Why does my contrastive learning model's loss and gradients explode during training?
I am fine-tuning an embedding model using contrastive learning. For the loss function, I’m using torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.
The training process initially seems to work fine — the loss decreases steadily on average. However, at some point during training (usually around step 16,000 in this case), the loss and gradients explode. After this, the model is unable to stabilize, and training becomes unusable.
Here is a graph showing the behavior:
Tensorboard loss by step graph
What I have tried so far:

Data preprocessing:

Removed outliers (e.g., very long texts).

Cleaned and filtered the dataset for consistency.



Hyperparameter tuning:

Adjusted the learning rate and tried different values.

Changed the optimizer (e.g., switching from Adam to SGD)



Gradient clipping:

Clipped gradients to a max norm of 1 using torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.



My setup:

Dataset size: ~14,000 samples

Model architecture: Transformer-based embedding model

Batch size: 1 (given my gpu capacity)

Learning rate: 1e-5

Optimizer: Adam with weight decay


Training loop (relevant part):
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    for step, batch in enumerate(dataset_train):
        temperature = max(0.1, 0.05 * (1 - step / num_training_steps))

        # Move data to device
        anchor_input_ids = batch["anchor_input_ids"].to(device)
        anchor_attention_mask = batch["anchor_attention_mask"].to(device)
        positive_input_ids = batch["positive_input_ids"].to(device)
        positive_attention_mask = batch["positive_attention_mask"].to(device)
        negative_input_ids = batch["negative_input_ids"].to(device)
        negative_attention_mask = batch["negative_attention_mask"].to(device)

        anchor_input_ids = anchor_input_ids.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch
        anchor_attention_mask = anchor_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch
        positive_input_ids = positive_input_ids.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch
        positive_attention_mask = positive_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch
        negative_input_ids = negative_input_ids.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch
        negative_attention_mask = negative_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0)  # Add a dimension for the batch

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Generate embeddings
        anchor_embeddings = model.forward(anchor_input_ids, anchor_attention_mask)
        positive_embeddings = model.forward(positive_input_ids, positive_attention_mask)
        negative_embeddings = model.forward(negative_input_ids, negative_attention_mask)

        # Calculate cosine similarities
        pos_sim = cosine_similarity(anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings)
        neg_sim = cosine_similarity(anchor_embeddings, negative_embeddings)

        # Calculate logits
        logits = torch.cat([pos_sim.unsqueeze(1), neg_sim.unsqueeze(1)], dim=1) / temperature
        labels = torch.zeros(logits.size(0), dtype=torch.long).to(device)  # The positive class is always the first

        # Calculate InfoNCE loss
        loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits, labels)
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

Dataset generation:
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import random

class FineTuneContrastiveDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pairs_data, df_1, df_2, tokenizer, max_tokens=512):
        """
        pairs_data: List of tuples (id_1, id_2, label).
        df_1: DataFrame containing text data associated with id_1.
        df_2: DataFrame containing text data associated with id_2.
        tokenizer: Hugging Face tokenizer.
        max_tokens: Maximum allowed length for the tokenized text.
        """
        self.pairs_data = pairs_data
        self.df_1 = df_1.set_index("id_1")
        self.df_2 = df_2.set_index("id_2")
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_tokens = max_tokens
        self.id_2_list = list(self.df_2.index)  # For selecting negative samples

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pairs_data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Retrieve data from the pair
        id_1, id_2_positive, label = self.pairs_data[idx]
        
        # Text associated with id_1 (anchor)
        text_1 = " ".join(self.df_1.loc[id_1]["chunks"])

        # Positive text associated with id_2
        text_2_positive = " ".join(self.df_2.loc[id_2_positive]["chunks"])

        # Generate a negative sample from id_2
        id_2_negative = random.choice(
            [candidate_id for candidate_id in self.id_2_list if candidate_id != id_2_positive]
        )
        text_2_negative = " ".join(self.df_2.loc[id_2_negative]["chunks"])

        # Tokenize inputs
        inputs_anchor = self.tokenizer(
            text_1, truncation=True, max_length=self.max_tokens, 
            padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt"
        )
        inputs_positive = self.tokenizer(
            text_2_positive, truncation=True, max_length=self.max_tokens, 
            padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt"
        )
        inputs_negative = self.tokenizer(
            text_2_negative, truncation=True, max_length=self.max_tokens, 
            padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt"
        )

        return {
            "anchor_input_ids": inputs_anchor["input_ids"].squeeze(0),
            "anchor_attention_mask": inputs_anchor["attention_mask"].squeeze(0),
            "positive_input_ids": inputs_positive["input_ids"].squeeze(0),
            "positive_attention_mask": inputs_positive["attention_mask"].squeeze(0),
            "negative_input_ids": inputs_negative["input_ids"].squeeze(0),
            "negative_attention_mask": inputs_negative["attention_mask"].squeeze(0),
            "label": torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.float),
            "id_1": id_1,
        }


Batch size = 1 seems problem to me. You are giving one data point at a time and because of this the updates in the weight has high varaince and it make the  convergence difficult and unstable.
And try to use Gradient Scaling Before Clipping.
